# hook_form_alter() only firing after cache clear

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I have a custom module that I'm using to add a Java applet to some of my admin forms. The applet is necessary to get details about the product being entered.

I'm noticing that after 15 minutes (or more) of site inactivity, my hook stops firing. If I clear the cache, the hook begins firing once again. However, this only seems to last 15 minutes or so.

Is it possible there is some admin form caching happening?

*Possibly salient details:*

- I'm using Seven as the admin theme
- I'm using D7 with Commerce Kickstart install profile (commerce_kickstart-7.x-1.8)

Comment: This might not be the best solution, but why not inside the hook_form_alter of the custom module you created you add drupal_flush_all_caches(); so that everytime you open the admin form the cache is clear and you always get the proper results. This should allow you to work while you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post the code of your hook_form_alter()? Or at least the form_id that you're checking for?

Comment: Provide code of your hook_form_alter() function

Comment: I cant comment yet or this would be a comment. It sounds like your caching level is to high? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_cache/7 while not an "answer" might help someone smarter than me answer it.

Comment: I'd echo what others have said: Can't answer the question without code. You might be altering the form in a way that bypasses Drupal's aggressive caching system.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem stands in **cascading caching logic** : your form must be called by something (a block, a template, a function...) that must be itself cached.

What you have to think about is **"When, and by who, is my cache warmed up, with which conditions ?"** : the most logical answer is that when your cache is created for the first time, conditions in your `hook_form_alter`are not TRUE.

For example, are you searching, in your alter, for infos coming from the session, or user roles, or static variables...

We could do more with your code :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. hook_form_alter() was not being called without clearing cache and thus the form incomplete. It was a form at admin panel (module config form).

Then I used the format hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm noticing that after 15 minutes (or more) of site inactivity, my hook stops firing**: If your `javascript` code does not work, as per my understanding that this is issue related to your `javascript`.

When the system is idle for few minute, `javascript` stopped working and generate the error. I was working in a project, I found the same issue and so I need to refresh browser to make it working after few minute if system is idle.

You can add some debug in your `hook_form_alter` and check that its working or not if system is idle for few minute.

Answer (score 0):

move your  hook_form_alter() in theme template.php , works each time