# form_alter cache weirdness

Tags: forms, caching

I use the following code to add some filter fields to the search form in a module:

```
function mymod_form_search_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id) {
    $q=drupal_get_query_parameters();
    if(isset($q["filter"])) {
            $values=[];
            foreach($q["filter"] as $k=>$v) {
                    if($v!=0)
                            $values[]=$k;
            }
    } else
            $values=[1,2,3,4];

    $form["filter"]=[
            "#type"=>"fieldset",
            "header"=>["#markup"=>"<h2>Filtern nach</h2>"],
            "checkbox"=>["#type"=>"checkboxes","#options"=>[1=>"Ausschreibung",2=>"News",3=>"Projekt",4=>"Experte"],"#default_value"=>$values],
            "submit"=>["#type"=>"submit","#value"=>"Anpassen"],
    ];
    $form["#submit"][]="mymod_search_form_submit";
}
```

When I now load the site once, the search form includes said filters. One `drush cc all` later (or when I post a new content) however the field disappears and I have to manually empty the `cache_form` DB table to make the field reappear temporarily.

Once I disable the caches with DrupalFakeCache however, I don't have that problem at all but site performance basically vanishes.

How do I fix that cache issue?

Comment: It's because you are using `drupal_get_query_parameters()` to create things that will be cached without respect to query parameters. Also, I don't see you sanitizing these? You just put query parameters as options of your form? Bad, bad idea. And after submit these query parameters will disappear, so any form rebuild will erase options and make your form processing inconsistent... If I understand what you meant there, nothing sort of serious redesign would help.

Comment: The problem is that search_by_page cannot filter by content types, I had to bolt that in with the provided sbp_query_modify. For sanitizing, the only place I use this is default_values which should be sanitized by drupal_render (or whatever renders the checkbox element).

As for why I'm using query parameters - well, the form submit goes to /search/search_by_page, and the search submit handler does a drupal_goto to /search/$keywords, so I take the values in mymod_search_form_submit and append them to the path in the redirect, so that the 2nd redirect ends up being /search/$keywords?filter=...

Comment: If you set default value not present in values, behavior is (as far as I know) undefined. It means that if it will break your site or shave your cat it will still be your fault.

Comment: You're right at that. But I managed to solve the problem by moving the form_alter and the submit handler to my site theme (after reading http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/157076/49665) - what on earth is the difference between modname_form_alter and themename_form_alter?!

Comment: Themes are cached with respect to query parameters.... (oversimplifying, I know)

Comment: That could explain it, but the fieldset, checkboxes and submit button are unconditionally added so it should have at least displayed the checkboxes when the code was in the module.